# Not getting admin email on order in open cart

Tags: opencart

I have configured the email in open cart. When I am adding product to cart and purchasing it

Then the mail is being sent to customer but not getting Admin notification plz help me what I am missing

Opencart version 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `system->settings->edit->option Tab` Here is an option named 'New Order Alert Mail', please make it yes if you wants to send notification email to owner (admin of the store).